# Java script (JQuery) do not work after dynamically changing tag attribute ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, anchor, rel

I have problem with running JS function when value or of `rel` attribute of `anchor` tag is changed, `anchor` look like this:

```
<a id="ThemeImageLink1" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)" class="preview"
rel="../Images/templateChooser/preview/preview1.jpg">
```

I am changing rel tag value from codebehind:

```
HtmlAnchor imageLink = (HtmlAnchor)getControlId(counter, "ThemeImageLink");
imageLink.Attributes.Add("rel","../Images/templateChooser/preview/preview2.jpg");
```

`getControlId` uses `FindControl()` to retrive Control from `aspx` page.

If i comment out part in code behind where I change `rel` attribute value jQuery works fine. Then jQuery script uses default value of `rel`

Here is jQuery part where I call function:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
         imagePreview();
    });
```

And functions implementation:

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

    $("a.preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.rel +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                 
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");    
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};
```

I also have other JavaScript functions witch are working fine, but this one gives me problems. 
Do you think I should call JS on PageLoad method?

Answer (score 0):

dont knwo more about asp.net  , but if rel attribute dynamic add then u have to use live event.

like  `$("a.preview").live('hover' , function(e){`

Comment: in this case better use `delegate`

Comment: new version of jquery .onmethod also